# Conflitos com a classe ConfideUser

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Na minha model **User**, deixei minha `protected $table = 'usuarios'` e em *auth.php* a mesma coisa, porém ao chamar o método `save()` do Eloquent, ele reconhece a tabela '**users**' e não '**usuarios**' como eu instanciei.

Sendo assim, renomeei em minha tabela do MySQL a tabela '**usuarios**' para '**users**' novamente, somente para teste, a partir disso ele reconheceu a tabela, mas o retorno do `save()` era sempre `bool = false`

Resolvi efetuar mais um teste alterando o cabeçalho da minha model **User** de

```php
class User extends ConfideUser implements PresentableInterface {
```

para

```php
class User extends Eloquent implements PresentableInterface {
```

e por incrível que pareça, voltou a funcionar normalmente. Minhas tabelas renomeadas funcionaram e o `save()` passou a funcionar também.

O que pode estar acontecendo? Não posso deixar dessa forma pois preciso da classe **Confide** em meu projeto.

Criei uma rota simples somente para teste:

```php
Route::get('teste', function(){
    $user = User::find(3);
    $user->background = 'teste';
    dd($user->save());
});
```

Minha Model User:

```php
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Confide\Confide;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideEloquentRepository;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;
use Robbo\Presenter\PresentableInterface;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class User extends ConfideUser implements PresentableInterface {
    use HasRole;

    public function getPresenter()
    {
        return new UserPresenter($this);
    }
    ...
```

Meu arquivo auth.php:

```php
<?php

return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'User',
    'table' => 'users',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve, segundo a orientação da documentação do pacote, usar a classe user da seguinte forma:

```php
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;

class User extends ConfideUser {

    // No seu caso, usando outra tabela:
    protected $table = 'usuarios';

}
```

Claro, você tentou isso, mas veja se não existe nenhum método sendo sobrescrito, remova a implementação da interface `PresentableInterface` e todos os métodos personalizados e faça o teste.

Se você estiver sobrescrevendo algum método poderá estar bugando alguma funcionalidade herdada.

Comment: deixei meu Model exatamente como descrito acima e o mesmo problema persiste. Tentei vasculhar para encontrar se há alguma class sobrescrevendo ela, mas não encontrei nada.

Comment: em conversa com o Zizaco, o mesmo me informou que o conflito pode estar nas dependências do Ardent.

Comment: Zizaco atualizou o confide para nao depender do Ardent, mas ainda assim estou tendo problemas ao salvar. Se faço alguma busca, ele me retorna o resultado ta tabela 'usuarios' normalmente, mas se uso o comando save() ou updateUniques(), ele tenta salvar na tabelas 'users'... sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo ?